# Question regarding convergent series of positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If we have two convergent series of positive reals, $∑b_n$ and $∑c_n$, can we find a third convergent series of positive reals, $∑a_n$ , such that  $\frac{a_n}{b_n }$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$ and $\frac{a_n}{c_n }$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$ ?

I know this can be done with specific series, but can it be done with arbitrary $∑b_n$ and $∑c_n$ ?

Comment: Make $u_n/b_n\to\infty$, make $v_n/c_n\to\infty$, let $a_n=\max(u_n,v_n)$.

Comment: Would $u_n$ and $v_n$ in this solution be sequences of positive reals, thus making $a_n$ also a sequence of positive reals? Using this solution, it seems it could be extended to find a suitable $a_n$ for any number of series we are given.

Comment: Yes. Any *finite* number of series.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed, this argument handles any finite number of series, but combining it with a diagonalization we should be able to handle any countable infinity of series.

Comment: @Andreas, yes, I expected as much, thanks.

Comment: You have placed your question in the wrong forum.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar my apologies for this, where would the correct forum be?

Comment: On those matters, I find almost always invaluable have a look at the wonderful book by Konrad Knopp, *Theory and application of infinite series*, Transl. from the 2nd ed. and revised in accordance with the fourth by R. C. H. Young. (English) London-Glasgow: Blackie & Son, Ltd. XII, 563 p. (1951), [Zbl 0042.29203](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0042.29203).

Comment: math.stackexchange.com **BUT** first read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @DanieleTampieri thank you so much for the book recommendation, I'll be sure to check this out.